# Why is my formula returning zero?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the formula:

`=IF(ISBLANK(AJ19),1,0)+SUM('Year to Date'!M19:X19)`

In cell `AQ19` but it is returning zero - it should be at least 1 (which is the number in AJ19)

Where am I going wrong?

[image]

Comment: Why the value in AJ19 is relevant, what matters there is only whether it's blank or not, as it's not blank, it'll contribute `0` to the result. Please evaluate your formula (formulas - evaluate) so you can follow step by step what is calculated.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about Formulas - Evaluate Formula @MátéJuhász I hadn't noticed that before.

Answer (score 2):

The first part of your formula does evaluate to 0.  If you follow Mate's suggestion, you'll get something like this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(AJ19),1,0)  
=IF(ISBLANK(1),1,0)
=IF(FALSE,1,0)  
=0
```

[Excel's IF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) works like this: `IF(Something is True, then do something, otherwise do something else)`

Your screenshot doesn't provide enough info to determine what worksheet 'Year to Date' refers to, whether the one presented or another.  But, assuming its the current, `SUM(M19:X19)` would also equal 0 (unless there's a hidden value in the cells).

Answer (score 0):

In your table Range M19:X19 is blank. That is the reason you are getting zero.

The first part of your formula is evaluated as False, since cell AJ19 is not blank, so 1 is not added to the values from M19:X19.

Check this screen shot.

[image]

The formula in M21 is, `=IF(ISBLANK(M18),1,0)+SUM(Sheet1!M19:R19)`

*I do hope this help you.*